# Not able to produce gaps between bars in matplotlib bar chart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am not able to produce gaps between every 3 bars in my bar chart produced by matplotlib in Python. Currently, all bars are clustered together and my aim is to have 1 bar width between every 3 bars in the graph. My code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 3

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

accu = [0.72, 0.99, 0.83]
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, accu, width, color='b')
prec = [0.99, 0.99, 0.81]
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, prec, width, color='y')
rec = [0.61, 0.99, 0.99]
rects3 = ax.bar(ind + 2 * width, rec, width, color='r')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores for each algorithm')
ax.set_xticks(ind + 1.5*width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('SVM', 'DecisionTree', 'NaiveBayes'))
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0]), ('Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall'))

plt.show()
```

The current standing plot is given below

[image: Bar chart with no gaps between every 3 bars]

Comment: make the width narrower?

Comment: ah, exactly what I need, thank you :)

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question and accept it (when the system will let you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @tacaswell, the gaps between bars was achieved by reducing the bar width. With width = 0.25, we get the following figure

[image: corrected graph]